# Restrict who can get live document updates without Firestore Rules nor Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to restrict access to document snapshot changes? (We are currently using .onSnapsho(). We don't want a random Tom to read our data.)

I believe the answer is using Firestore Rules or Firebase Authentication (e.g. logging in using your Google email) **but is there a different way?**

Current situation:

- For **writing** to the Firestore, we call a Firebase Function, and the **URL contains a MD5 query** that can be used to authenticate the request. Once authenticated, the Function writes to the DB.
- Is there something similar (like using something like an MD5 query) to receive document updates? (You should only be able to receive updates if you're authenticated somehow.)

Answer (score 1):

*I'm going to ignore the last line of your question, because you're contradicting yourself there on wanting/not wanting the user to authenticate.*

Aside from that: you could use the MD5 value as (part of) the ID of the document. Then you'd set your rules to:

- Not allow `list` calls on the collection.
- Allow `get` calls on any document.

That way, one can only read a document when one knows the ID of that document already in some way. This sort of security-by-obscurity is quite common, and can be (depending on the length and entropy of the keys used) be quite secure.

But the key essentially comes a never-expiring bearer token in this scenario, so you must be willing to accept that anyone who ever gets the key can access the document.